# valid HTTP connector, valid Blob connector but no file downloads?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps

I have a URL that points to a ZIP file and I want to have a logic app that takes that ZIP file and downloads it to a blob.

I've created an HTTP action with GET as the method and validated the URL is accurate and the payload (a ZIP file) downloads as expected when I browse to the URL.  No other data is in the HTTP action.

I've created an Azure blob storage action that I've confirmed can receive data.

I cannot seem to figure out the syntax to actually connect the HTTP action to download the approximately 3MB ZIP file to the Azure blob storage.  I've tried every combination of dynamic inputs but something isn't working.

Code with confidential keys and identifying details removed:

```
{
"$connections": {
    "value": {
        "azureblob": {
            "connectionId": "/subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/Default-SQL-CentralUS/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob",
            "connectionName": "azureblob",
            "id": "/subscriptions/XXX/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/azureblob"
        }
    }
},
"definition": {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
    "actions": {
        "Create_blob": {
            "inputs": {
                "body": "@variables('fileAccessURL')",
                "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
                },
                "host": {
                    "connection": {
                        "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                    }
                },
                "method": "post",
                "path": "/datasets/default/files",
                "queries": {
                    "folderPath": "/validis",
                    "name": "logicapptest",
                    "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                }
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "DownloadZIP": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "runtimeConfiguration": {
                "contentTransfer": {
                    "transferMode": "Chunked"
                }
            },
            "type": "ApiConnection"
        },
        "DownloadZIP": {
            "inputs": {
                "method": "GET",
                "uri": "@variables('fileAccessURL')"
            },
            "operationOptions": "DisableAutomaticDecompression",
            "runAfter": {
                "SetFileAccessURL": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "Http"
        },
        "InitializeAccessToken": {
            "inputs": {
                "variables": [
                    {
                        "name": "access_token",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "runAfter": {},
            "type": "InitializeVariable"
        },
        "InitializeFileAccessURL": {
            "inputs": {
                "variables": [
                    {
                        "name": "fileAccessURL",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "InitializeAccessToken": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "InitializeVariable"
        },
        "POST-AuthKey": {
            "inputs": {
                "body": "grant_type=vapi_key&key=XXX",
                "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "XXX",
                    "cache-control": "no-cache"
                },
                "method": "POST",
                "uri": "https://api.sandbox.XXX.com/v1/oauth/token"
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "InitializeFileAccessURL": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "Http"
        },
        "RetrieveZIP_URL": {
            "inputs": {
                "headers": {
                    "Authorization": "@{concat('Bearer ',variables('access_token'))}",
                    "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "XXX",
                    "cache-control": "no-cache"
                },
                "method": "GET",
                "uri": "https://api.sandbox.XXX.com/v1/extracts/general-ledger/engagements/XXX"
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "SetAccessToken": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "Http"
        },
        "SetAccessToken": {
            "inputs": {
                "name": "access_token",
                "value": "@{body('POST-AuthKey').access_token}"
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "POST-AuthKey": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "SetVariable"
        },
        "SetFileAccessURL": {
            "inputs": {
                "name": "fileAccessURL",
                "value": "@{body('RetrieveZIP_URL').fileaccessurl}"
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "RetrieveZIP_URL": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "SetVariable"
        }
    },
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "outputs": {},
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "defaultValue": {},
            "type": "Object"
        }
    },
    "triggers": {
        "Recurrence": {
            "recurrence": {
                "frequency": "Month",
                "interval": 12
            },
            "type": "Recurrence"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide details if you are getting any error ? Have you tried passing extension name (.zip) as part of the file name.

Comment: thanks for the reminder, yes that was the trick, I just needed to add ".zip" to the file name and worked like a charm.

Comment: Great to hear that it worked :)